# Overflow Error when using Newton's Method in Python

Tags: python, newtons-method

I am trying to carry out the Newton's method in Python to solve a problem. I have followed the approach of some examples but I am getting an Overflow Error. Do you have any idea what is causing this?

```
def f1(x):
    return x**3-(2.*x)-5.

def df1(x):
    return (3.*x**2)-2.


def Newton(f, df, x, tol):

    while True:
        x1 = f(x) - (f(x)/df(x))

        t = abs(x1-x)

        if t < tol:
            break
        x = x1

    return x


init = 2



print Newton(f1,df1,init,0.000001)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html ? FWIW, my favorite is fmin_l_bfgs_b. Did you try using a function to check that your objective and gradient are consistent?

Comment: It could be homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newton's method is

[image: Newton's method]

so `x1 = f(x) - (f(x)/df(x))`

should be

x1 = **x** - (f(x)/df(x))

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code. It should be

```
def Newton(f, df, x, tol):

    while True:
        x1 = x - (f(x)/df(x))  # it was f(x) - (f(x)/df(x))

        t = abs(x1-x)

        if t < tol:
            break
        x = x1

    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

The equation you're solving is cubic, so there are two values of x where df(x)=0. Dividing by zero or a value close to zero will cause an overflow, so you need to avoid doing that.

One practical consideration for Newton's algorithm is how to handle values of x near local maxima or minima. Overflow is likely caused by dividing by something near zero. You can show this by adding a print statement before your `x=` line -- print x and df(x).  To avoid this problem, you can calculate `df(x)` before dividing, and if it's below some threshold, bump the value of x up or down a small amount and try again.